# Why was it relevant that Aoi used her World during the battle at the end of episode 4?

Tags: qualidea-code

In the battle at the end of episode 4, Canaria and Aoi get flown into Tokyo Bay by two Tokyo students, shortly before Suzaku flies Himekawa into point-blank range of the Leviathan-class Unknown to wipe it out. Upon arrival, Canaria employs her World to fortify/power-up the other combatants. Well enough.

However, Suzaku comments that Canaria's World is being combined/overlain with Aoi's World (which, as you will recall, is the ability to record and retransmit people's perceptions). This is probably what Canaria asked Aoi to do just before she started singing.

But why is this relevant? I can't think of any useful effect Aoi's World could have here, nor did I see anything to indicate that anyone was receiving any perceptions transmitted by Aoi.